# Meteor Jade Handlebars on Windows 8 - Jade compiler error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, pug, meteorite

I'm attempting to use jade in meteor with this package https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars

I'm on a windows machine. I've so far managed to use most meteorite packages by following the instructions here (www.discovermeteor.com/2013/03/20/using-meteor-and-atmopshere-on-windows/)

When i run 'meteor' on my project with .jade files, I'm getting this error:

```
While building the application:
client\todos.jade: Jade compiler error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefin
ed

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

I tried to use this new fork too -> https://github.com/kynan/meteor-jade-handlebars/tree/refactor-for-meteor-0.6.5

Same problem.

I further tested this in a Linux machine and it works perfectly. I have no idea why this is failing with the above mention error on windows.

Comment: To diagnose this issue further you'll need to pin down which use of `length` is cause the problem and therefore where the undefined value came from. It is unfortunate that there isn't a stack trace output - maybe you could try modifying the jade package to print out the stack when the error occurs?

Comment: Same here, also using the new fork by kynan. If a character is in the `.jade` file it throws the error, when the file is empty it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a blank extra line to the end of your file. For example, an extra line would be needed here.

```
template(name="name")
    h1 Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a lot of problems getting `jade-templating` to work with `meteor`, but finally got it to work.. Here's how:

Add this to `smart.json`, belt-jade-handlebars is jade for newer versions of meteor:

```
"packages": {
  "belt-jade-handlebars": {}
}
```

Add this to `.meteor/packages`:

```
belt-jade-handlebars
```

And finally add the extra blank line to all `*.jade` files. ( suggested by user3064375 )

Start the app by using:

```
$ meteor run --release template-engine-preview-3
```

This will use the latest template engine and start meteor.